# Add Rails minitest fixtures for a single test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, minitest, fixtures

Is there a way to a `Rails` `minitest` fixtures just for one specific test or set of tests?  I ask because I want to display `Delayed::Job` jobs using the standard `index/show/delete` schemes so I want to fake some `Delayed::Job` objects to test my views.  But I don't want these objects present when I actually test my `Delayed::Job` processing code so I'd like to add then just for once specific set of tests.

Comment: Have you considered a factory pattern for these cases? Then you can just build the objects on demand. It could be as simple as building the objects in a _setup_ method or maybe [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) would help?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which creates the testing data/fixtures, and call that function before the test. like

```
def test_user_delete
  create_user
  ...
  ...
end

private    
def create_user
  User.create(...)
end
```

Comment: Thanks both.  I've not had a chance to try your methods but a heads-up that one problem I was hitting seems to be a bug in `paranoia`; upgrading from `paranoia` 1.2.0 to 2.2.0 solved it.  The bug was causing a strange error about default_scope that seems to be related to how `paranoia` inserts itself into my `delayed_jobs` class.